# Add ... after x characters if string too long in grocery crud in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

I have a description field in my MySQL database, and I access the database on two different pages, one page I display the whole field, but on the other, I just want to display the first 50 characters.

If the string in the description field is less than 50 characters, then it won't show ... , but if it isn't, I will show ... after the first 50 characters.

Comment: you can use word_limiter or  character_limiter of CI text helper

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You can do it with `codeigniter` `text` helper* , load text helper in `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('text');
```

Either use `word_limiter()` like this

```
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";

$string = word_limiter($string, 4,'...');
```

or use `character_limiter()` like this

```
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words. and so on";
$string = character_limiter($string, 50,'...');
```

In your case use `character_limiter()`

For reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html

Comment: if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to check it as green

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->load->helper('text');` this for set character
limits and also you can set up using `substr` function.

```
$this->load->helper('text');
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";
echo $string = character_limiter($string, 20);  // using text helper in codeigniter
echo substr($string, 0,10);  // using substr . start from 0 and end on 10
```